# Determine convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, conditional-convergence

Let a series be given as
$$\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\pi m)}{\ln(\ln(m))}$$

Is it converges conditionally, converges absolutely or diverges.

**Attempt**

From computation I see that it does indeed converge (and I can show that it converges using alternating series test / Leibnitz). The thing that is left is to show that the $$\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\left | \frac{\cos(\pi k)}{\log(\log(k))} \right |$$
diverges and thus that it does not converge  absolutely but only conditionally. But trying to use that if $a_n$ does not converge to $0$ then the series diverges I get stock as I see that the sequence $a_n$ does converge to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have $\cos(\pi m)=(-1)^m$, so we may write
$$\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\left | \frac{\cos(\pi m)}{\log(\log(m))} \right |=\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\left | \frac{(-1)^m}{\log(\log(m))} \right|=\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lvert\log(\log(m))\rvert}.$$
Also observe that $\log\log m <m$ for $m>1$. So a lower bound is the harmonic series.

Comment: So the lower bound being divergent means that this is divergent, right?

Comment: Yes, $\infty<A\Rightarrow A\to\infty$. Lower bound is used loosely here since both series are divergent.

Comment: Hmm but itsn't it significant that it should indeed be a lower bound or else this is inconclusive?

Comment: @mathstudent23 I fixed the typo. Now the inequality sign is correct.

Comment: Why does the inequaility for $\log\log(m)<$ for $m>1$ hold?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741600/prove-that-logx-x-for-x-0-x-in-mathbbn) post. You can use analogous arguments for $\log\log m$ instead of $\log m$. (Or observe that $\log m<m$ implies $\log\log m< \log m$ and from both inequalities that $\log\log m <m$ )

Comment: @mathstudent23 I'm not quite sure what you mean. I have not used "$n$" in my answer. If you mean $m$: Not one of the statements in my answer ($\cos(\pi m)=(-1)^m, \log\log m<m, \log m<m$) do not hold for $m=3$.

Comment: My confusion is with this. The series $\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\log(\log(m))}$ is not positive for all $m$ which we demanded by taking the absolut value? take $m=2$ for example. Is this not a problem?

Comment: @mathstudent23 The series, which you wrote is positive. You wanted to prove that the series does not converge absolutely and the answer above provides a proof.

Comment: I meant take $m=2$ which gives the approx $-2.7$.

Comment: Note that the series runs over $m$, so $m$ does not have *one* value. Are you talking about the lower bound? If that's the case, still [not true](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+m%3D2+to+inf+of+1%2F%28log%28log+m%29%29).

Comment: I am talking about the lower bound yes since it is demanded that $b_n\leq a_n$ for alle $n \in \mathbb{N}$ to compare. The series of $b_n$ converges if the series $a_n$ converges. the series of $a_n$ diverges if the series of $b_n$ diverges

Comment: @mathstudent23 It is not clear what you're asking. Throwing with expressions $a_n,b_n$ and $m=2$ and $n$ is not understandable at all. Write a *clear* comment, maybe use Google Translate.

Comment: @mathstudent23 Should I answer your new question too?

Comment: My confusion is just from the fact that I am unsure on the fact that if my series is from the index $n=2$ can I then consider $n=3$ without losing properties of convergence etc.

Comment: @mathstudent23 This is not a problem at all. Convergence is about the "last" terms of an infinite series and not about the first ones. You can write $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_n=a_2+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}a_n$$ to study convergence of a series, which starts at $3$.

Comment: My book states that: let $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_n$ and $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} b_n$ be 2 positive series with $b_n\leq a_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}b_n$ converges if $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_n$ converges. $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_n$ diverges if $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}b_n$ diverges.

Comment: Now, the "for all $n$" seems to me to destroy this argument for divergence since comparing with the harmonic series terms $1/n$ for $n=2$ obviously fails as $\frac{1}{\ln(ln(n))}$ is negativ.

Comment: @mathstudent23 Absolutely nothing "destroys" the argument. I thought it was a trivial step so I didn't write it out.

Comment: so just let $n \geq 3$?

Comment: @mathstudent23 In order to use the comparison test, $n\ge3$ yes (of course) *but* the harmonic series is still a "lower bound" for the series if $n\ge2$. This step is trivial and even explained in my comment with the two big sums.

Comment: But the inequality in your post says $\ln(\ln(x))<x$ but I have to consider $|\ln(\ln(x))|<x$ for $x>1$. Graphing thoes I see that i need $x>1.31$.

Comment: @mathstudent23 I understand what you mean and you are correct. Nonetheless the inequality in my post is still true but is only applied for $m\ge3$ (we can omit the absolut value) since I skipped the trivial step of neglecting the constant at $m=2$.

Comment: But still. Consider using alternating test for the series in question to prove convergence. You can not do that with $n=2$. That is why I am wondering how that would look if I choose $n=3$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124719/discussion-between-vitamin-d-and-mathstudent23).