# Does $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(k)}{\log(\log(k))}$ converge?

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, trigonometric-series

Does
$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(k)}{\log(\log(k))}$
converge?

According to Wolfy,
it seems to converge
to about -8.80.

This is suggested by
[Determine convergence of a series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4145756/determine-convergence-of-a-series)

This could possibly be done
by looking at the $k$ for which
$m < \log(\log(k)) < m+1
$
(or $e^{e^m} < k < e^{e^{m+1}}$)
and looking at
$\dfrac1{m}\sum\cos(k)$
in this region
and showing that it is
small enough so that
the sum of these converges.

The fact that
$\sum_{k=1}^m \cos(k)$
is bounded
would probably be useful,
but I don't think that
this is enough.

Comment: If you've proven that the partial sums of the cos(k) are bounded, then you can use Dirichlet's test.

Answer (score 1):

By [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) and the fact $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \cos(k)$ is bounded, $\frac{1}{\log\log(k)} \to 0$ is monotone, we're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use Diriclet's test here if I am not wrong, as the sum of cos(k) is bounded and 1/log(log(k)) is monotone and approaches 0.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the following
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \cos k = \frac{2}{\sin 1}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin(k+1)-\sin (k-1)$$
to prove the boundedness of the sum of $\cos$'s.