# prove logarithmic function is big oh of non logarithmic function

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

I am having trouble knowing how to find out whether a given logarithmic function, |f(x)|, is an element of the set of all functions less than or equal to C * |g(x)| where g(x) is a non-logarithmic function for some C and k such that x > k.

For example:

Say I am trying to prove that:

|N log N| <= C * |N^3| for some C and k where x > k

A way to establish whether this statement is true would be to solve for C. If C is not a function of N, then the statement holds true. To better be able to divide f(x) by g(x) to get a useful value would be to increase f(x). If f'(x) is still less than C * g(x) then we can still divide it by g(x) to get a useful value for C that can help prove whether the initial statement is true.

My struggle is what do I do if I am comparing a logarithmic function to a non-logarithmic function? It seems like it would be extremely difficult to increase N log N in to something that can be divided by N^3. Is there a way to do this? I have been doing research on logarithms and have not, so far, been able to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use limits to prove this, or you could prove it algebraically as follows:

For all $n \ge 1$,
$$n \le e^n$$
$$ \log n \le \log e^n$$
$$ \log n \le n$$
$$ n \cdot \log n \le n \cdot n^2$$
$$ n \log n \le n^3$$
Hence,
$$n \log n = O(n^3)$$

Comment: I understand everything except the second to last step where you multiply log n by n and n by n^2. Why are you able to do that?

Comment: is it because it is not an equality statement but an inequality statement?

Comment: Exactly. The statement is an inequality, so there is no requirement to multiply both sides by the same quantity - as long as the inequality still holds. In this case $n \le n^2$ for $n \ge 1$, so if $a \le b$, then $an \le bn^2$. This sort of technique is used all the time with inequalities.

Comment: If you are satisfied with your answer, then please click the green check to close the post. Thanks!

Comment: Also how does log e^n = n? Wouldn't it equal whatever exponent value would make e = n?

Comment: And once I understand all of the answer, I will definitely upvote it.

Comment: Or is that you are just replacing log e^n with n since we know that n > log n?

Comment: $\log e^n$ is a power of $e$ that results in $e^n$. This power would be $n$. Hence, $\log e^n = n$. Maybe you are confused becuase I am expressing the natural logarithm with $\log$ instead of $\ln$? Using the two interchangeably is common in mathematics, albeit not so much in other disciplines where $\log$ is taken to mean the common logarithm (base $10$). If you interpret $\log$ as the common logairthm, the proof still holds up as long as you replace $e$ with $10$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100030/discussion-between-darien-springer-and-ryry-the-fly-guy).

Comment: For some reason I cant submit in chat... I think you have the right idea but are reading the notation incorrectly. When I write log e^n, you are seeing "log base e of n," or in other words, what power of e results in n. However, what I mean is "log base e of e raised to a power of n," or in other words, what power of e results in e^n. You see the argument of the logarithm as n, but really my argument is e^n. The base of my logarithm is not explicitly stated becuase all I have is "log." When the base is not explicitly stated in mathematics, it is often assumed to be base e.

Comment: You are totally right. I was misreading that. Thanks!

Comment: Another question, why are we allowed to assume the base here when it isn't given? Or does the base matter when trying to break these algorithms down?

Comment: In general, it is important for the base of a logarithm to be stated, even if it is completely arbitrary. The reason we may assume the base above is purely a matter of convention (i.e. there is no mathematical justification for it; it's a habit among mathematicians born out of convenience). In mathematics, a logarithm of base e is used so often that mathematicians stopped stating it explicitly. So now, whenever you see a logarithm with no base stated, you can assume it's base e. If the base is not e, then you should state the base explicitly as in $log_2 8 = 3$

Comment: Okay. So my question now is I could use any base and get the result above?

Comment: Yes, you can change the base of the logarithm as long as you change $e$ to be whatever the base is... you will end up with the same result

Comment: What if we aren't allowed to assume the base? Would there be any way to simplify both sides the way we have here?

Comment: Yes. Just call the base some arbitrary $b>1$ and replace $e$ with $b$. For example, for all $n \ge 1$, we have $n \le b^n$ where $b > 1$. Take $\log_b$ of both sides of the inequality and proceed with the proof the same as before to arrive at the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\log{(n)}}{n^3}=0\implies n\log{n}=o(n^3)$$
i.e. the statement is true $\forall \,C\gt0$ as long as $k$ is suitably chosen.

Comment: Yes but can I prove this more algebraically? In this case I have to just assume that as n approaches infinity that n^3, for some value of C and k when x > k, will grow faster than n log n forever after that point. Because if I just prove that one function will reach a point where it grows faster than the other using the assumption that one grows faster than the other, then haven't I used circular reasoning? Or am I misunderstanding your reasoning here?

Comment: Maybe you could use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380963/prove-that-log-x-x-for-all-x-0) question?